# How do I replace the white color in my image with a gold yellow. Lightroom Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I replace the white color in my image with a gold yellow. There are tons of things of this for Photoshop CC, but I cant find anything for Photoshop lightroom.

Answer (score 0):

Select the white with the **magic wand** tool and then color in the selection with the color of your choice. This should help.